# Problem installing rgbdslam, missing octomap

Tags: ros, rosdep, octomap, catkin, rgbdslam-freiburg

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I'm running into some problems installing rgbdslam on my turtlebot.  I followed the instructions on the wiki (http://www.ros.org/wiki/rgbdslam).

When I try to install with (rosdep install rgbdslam_freiburg) I get the error

ERROR: Rosdep cannot find all required resources to answer your query
Missing resource octomap

I already installed octomap with (sudo apt-get install ros-fuerte-octomap) but it still gives me this error.

**UDATE**  I deleted rgbdslam and started over.  Now it have the octomap working but getting a new error

ERROR: the following packages/stacks could not have their rosdep keys resolved
to system dependencies:
rgbdslam: Missing resource catkin

I can roscd to catkin and the path is in the ROS_PACKAGE_PATH so I'm not sure what's going on.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/56667/problem-installing-rgbdslam,-missing-octomap/) by [jd](https://answers.ros.org/users/2939/jd/) on ROS Answers with karma: 62 on 2013-02-28

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Felix Endres](https://answers.ros.org/users/113/felix-endres/) on 2013-02-28**:
Hm, I don't know why rgbdslam should need catkin, but do you have ros-fuerte-octomap-mapping installed?

**Comment by [jd](https://answers.ros.org/users/2939/jd/) on 2013-03-02**:
Thanks, I got octomap mapping now.  I'm running into the same catkin error when I try to install octomap though.

**Comment by [Felix Endres](https://answers.ros.org/users/113/felix-endres/) on 2013-03-03**:
Weird. I have no idea what this is, sorry.

**Comment by [LivingMachine](https://answers.ros.org/users/2201/livingmachine/) on 2013-03-20**:
Thanks Felix, I just need todo "sudo apt-get install ros-fuerte-octomap-mapping"

**Comment by [Lili Meng](https://answers.ros.org/users/2899/lili-meng/) on 2014-05-06**:
Hi Jd, have you solved the problem? As I encountered the same problem.  rgbdslam: Missing resource catkin

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I have faced these problems many times. And when I face these problems, I would first run this command:

```
aptitude search octomap
```

then the Terminal will give me all of the packages that contained  "octomap", and would tell me whether the package is installed, "p" means has not installed yet, and "i" means has already installed.

Then you can run the command "sudo apt-get install ..." to install the missing package.

And sorry for my poor English...

---

Originally posted by [tanghz](https://answers.ros.org/users/21137/tanghz/) with karma: 130 on 2015-01-19

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2